# Access violation writing location 0x011CF000

Tags: c, bmp

I'm trying to get monochrome image from .bmp image with using bitmap_image.hpp library. But in one place (Pic[i][j] = 0.3 * r + 0.59 * g + 0.11 * b;) i receive that error: Unhandled exception at 0x0019BD8F in PicCircle.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x011CF000. . So, that's wrong with it?

code:

```
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"

#define C 0.01

double** ArrayCreate ( int M, int N )
{
    int i;
    double** ArrayRoot;

    ArrayRoot = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*) * M);

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        ArrayRoot[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * N);

    return ArrayRoot;
}

void ArrayDestroy ( double** Array , int M)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Array[i] = (double *)realloc(Array[i], 0);
    };

    Array = (double **)realloc(Array, 0);
}

void main ( void )
{
    double** Pic;
    unsigned char r, g, b;
    int H, W, i, j;

    bitmap_image image("m1.bmp");

    H = image.height();
    W = image.width();

    Pic = ArrayCreate(H, W);


    for (i = 0; i < W; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++)
        {
            image.get_pixel(i, j, r, g, b);
            Pic[i][j] = 0.3 * r + 0.59 * g + 0.11 * b;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < W; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++)
        {
            if (abs(sqrt(pow(Pic[i + 1][j] - Pic[i][j], 2) + pow(Pic[i][j + 1]  - Pic[i][j], 2))) >= C)
                Pic[i][j] = 1;
            else
                Pic[i][j] = 0;
        }


    ArrayDestroy(Pic, H);
}
```

Comment: Minor: Suggest `free(Array[i]); Array[i] = NULL;` rather than `Array[i] = (double *)realloc(Array[i], 0);`.  Passing a 0 to `realloc(ptr, 0)` does not guarantee freeing all memory.

Comment: `image.get_pixel(i, j, r, g, b);` -- can we see what `get_pixel` does? You do not appear to pass these variables by reference.

Answer (score 2):

In your first loop you access the `Pic` array as `Pic[width][height]`, but in the second loop you access it as `Pic[height][width]`.
One of those two is incorrect, probably the first one.

Fixing your `for` loop should correct the issue.

Comment: Yes, don't observed it. Now it's fixed. But still, problem appears earlier than second for, so problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
ArrayRoot = (double **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * M);
```

looks super-broken; it assumes `sizeof (int *)` to be the same as `(sizeof double *)` which is probably true, but still a very broken thing to write.

The follow-up is worse:

```
ArrayRoot[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

since `sizeof (int)` is very probably smaller than `sizeof (double)` this is going to lead to horror.

The way to avoid this category of error is to never write the type name in the `malloc()` argument: dereference the pointer being assigned to, instead. The latter would then become:

```
ArrayRoot[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *ArrayRoot[i]);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                  this part is to
                                  the left of the =
```

This also [drops the cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) of course.

Comment: Ops, thanks, copied that part for int and didn't change all types. Fixed it, but error is still appears it that place, but now it is "Unhandled exception at 0x00D4BD8F in PicCircle.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFDFDFDFD.".

Comment: +1, especially for `ArrayRoot[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *ArrayRoot[i])`